# Streamlit multiselect doesn't perform properly

Tags: python, streamlit

I wrote the code as follows for streamlit app. I read data frame which is output of other function.
The codes works in a way that I can select item in multi select, however when I select item in multi select, it runs and doesn't update the data frame. how should I fix this issue?

```
#CODE is the dataframe columns that I perform filtering.
def do_something():

    return df  

df = do_something()

def select(df):

    x= df.CODE.unique().tolist()
    codes= st.columns([0.1, 0.1])

    codes = codes.multiselect("Select Code", x, key={"key1"})

    if codes:
        df = df.query("CODE in @codes)

    return df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you just need to *re-assign* your DataFrame after/when calling `select`.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

def do_something():
    df = pd.DataFrame({"CODE": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
                       "VALUE": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
    return df

def select(df):
    x = df.CODE.unique().tolist()
    codes = st.multiselect("Select Code", x, key="key1")

    if codes:
        df = df.query("CODE in @codes")

    return df

df = do_something()
st.write("BEFORE:")
st.write(df)

df = select(df) # <---- add this line
st.write("AFTER:")
st.write(df)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I tried this way on my code and still it doesnt update data frame, I put the code as a version 2 in my question, I dont know what I am doing wrong ? maybe you can have a look?

Comment: Sure, when/how do you define `start_dt`, `end_dt` and `s2_dt` ? With `load_data` I suppose but can you tell what's their types ?

Comment: Thank you, I define it in the very first  function when I load the data and do some cleaning,  and I call the function like this : 

dataframes_list,s2_dt,start_dt,end_dt= load_data(id)

Comment: Thanks but what's their respective types ? For examples what gives `print(type(s2_dt))` ?

Comment: It is a time, like start_dt and end_dt, but another time in between

Comment: Can you `print(type(start_dt, end_dt, s2_dt))` to see the exact type, please ?

Comment: which I generate this time in the first function

Comment: it is datetime.date

Comment: <class 'datetime.date'>

Comment: I made some minor changes in your second code, can you check please (https://pastebin.com/gvUTGxqc) ? I tested it and the dataframe is being filtered two times (first, after the timeslider and second, after the multiselect). Make sure to readapt it so it matches your actual code/dataset.